# Time based distributed search

Tags: search, distributed

I have a stream of notifications coming at a high rate (about 5 per ms). They are currently stored in a distributed no-sql db indexed by a guid attached with each notification. I want to make them searchable by time.

An example query would be return all notification between 5 and 6 pm from tomorrow.
To begin with I would like to keep the data searchable for a week.

I want to know if there is well-known solution for implementing such time based search for distributed systems?